# Clickhouse Array Join with Left Join and Computed Counts

Tags: clickhouse

I have a SearchImpressions table that has a nested type column that holds arrays of Product_Id and Price that were shown during a search. I also have a table that holds the details on when a user clicks on one of the search results.

**Question:**

Given a product id I would like to find out the total impressions and the count of clicks grouped by day.

**Product Search Results Table**

EventDateTime Query Results(ProductId[], Price[])

**Product Clicks Table**

EventDateTime ProductId

**Required Output**

```
EventDate    ProductId TotalImpressions TotalClicks

11-11-2020   0001      56               6
12-11-2020   0002      21               0
```

I have attempted this but both counts appear the same

```
SELECT pr.EventDate,
       impressions.ProductId,
       count(impressions.ProductId) As TotalImpressions,
       count(clicks.productId) as TotalClicks
FROM ProductResults pr
ARRAY JOIN results as impressions
LEFT JOIN ProductClicks clicks on
          impressions.ProductId = clicks.ProductId
GROUP BY pr.EventDate,
         pr.DealershipId,
         pr.Vrm
ORDER BY pr.EventDate Desc;
```

Thanks

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Required Output -- for what input ?

Comment: @DennyCrane Apologies it is not clear - I simply would like to know how to get a count of Products that were returned in search results and how many times they were clicked per day for instance, not bothered which search the click came from I just need to show Product 1 was returned 30 times in search and clicked on twice on any given day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like need to add predicate to count-aggregate function for *clicks.productId* or use uniqIf-function:

```sql
SELECT pr.EventDate,
       impressions.ProductId,
       count(impressions.ProductId) As TotalImpressions,
       countIf(clicks.productId != 0) as TotalClicks1 /* <-- v.1 */
       uniqIf(clicks.productId, clicks.productId != 0) as TotalClicks2 /* <-- v.2 */
..
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT pr.EventDate,
        impressions.ProductId,
        count() As TotalImpressions,
        clicks.TotalClicks
 FROM ProductResults pr ARRAY JOIN results as impressions
 LEFT JOIN    (select ProductId, count(clicks.productId) TotalClicks 
               from  ProductClicks group by ProductId 
              ) clicks on impressions.ProductId = clicks.ProductId
 GROUP BY pr.EventDate, impressions.ProductId
 ORDER BY pr.EventDate Desc;
```